# Pointer to function as parameter, using typedef

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm trying to create code which uses pointers to functions as parameteres, and I have to use a typedef.
I'm not a C pro. It feels like I'm getting there, but I can't seem to find a good explanation of the syntax of pointers to function.

I have a function fillArray:

```
long fillArray(long *array, int x, int y) {
//
}
```

then I want to make a typedef of a pointer to this function:

```
typedef long (*fArray)(long, int, int);

fArray pFill = fillArray;
```

and I want to give this pFill to a function called doThis():

```
int doThis (fArray pFill) {
  return 0;
}
```

and calling it using:

```
int y = doThis(pFill);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your typedef needs to be:

```
typedef long (*fArray)(long *, int, int);
                            ^
```

Comment: Great! Kinda lame that I didn't see this myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your `fillArray` function accepts a `long *` as first parameter, you forgot a `*` into the `typedef`:

```
typedef long (*fArray)(long *, int, int);
```